# discord bots - what am I doing wrong in this code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm following the guide on discordjs.guides, and am at the end of the command handling guide. I've followed the steps provided and my code looks exactly like the code they've given, just with some of the filenames changed, and yet I get this error:

> "Error: Cannot find module './commands/${file}'"

I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what's causing this error. I've looked at other questions about similar issues, but the solutions I've found don't seem to be working for me - for instance one solution was to add an extra period to the beginning of the expression, but this didn't work for me.

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./auth.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require('./commands/${file}');
    //Set a new item in the Collection
    //With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});


// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Please show us some code. Take a look at [ask] and [tour] about creating a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is using

```js
require('./commands/${file}');
```

You should actually use

```js
require(`./commands/${file}`);
```

Note how the `${file}` variable in the second example is black, while in the first one it remains green. This is because the basic quotation doesn't allow escaping variables, so, when you're trying to require that module with basic quotation, you code looks for a module called `${file}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never would have noticed that. So if I'm understanding it right, I would use backticks on require functions that are searching for a variable item - such as everything in a folder, like there - and normal single quotes for a fixed file, such as earlier when I link my auth file?

Comment: @cobaltSniper this is called a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)